# Animate tab switch with TabHost

Tags: android, animation

Hi: When the user clicks on another tab an animation should appear to the next view? What is the best to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, no animation is applied, at least on honeycomb. The view will just pop on.

You could do something like this if you wanted to animate it:

Find the child of the tab and play an animation on it.

Example:
First set a listener:

```
exampleTabhost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId)
            {
                refreshTabHostUI(exampleTabhost);
            }
        });
```

In your listener play the animation on your tab:

```
View tab1 = th.findViewById(R.id.tab1);
    if( tab1 != null )
        playAnim(tab1, getBaseContext(), android.R.anim.fade_in, 500);
```

Play anim function:

```
public Animation playAnim( View v, Context con, int animationid, int startOffset )
    {
        if( v != null )
        {
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(con, animationid  );
            animation.setStartOffset(startOffset);
            v.startAnimation(animation);

            return animation;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Alternatively, setLayoutAnimation (and the layoutAnimation XML attribute) might provide an easier way to do the same. I haven't tested it, though.